# Arts based magic system, parallel world

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

As I recall, it had a universe parallel to our own, where people have some sort of magic system that works by drawing or something like that. I read a French version (likely translated) where the magic was called "dessin", literally "drawing" in French, ~15 years ago. I'm not entirely sure about the setting, but probably medieval fantasy for the parallel world, and modern for the regular one.

At some point, the two young (teens) main characters, which live in the parallel world, are split up, with one of them being sent out / kidnapped / ?, to an isolated place / factory thing in the countryside, in the regular world, where they extract the magic power from the children. I'm fairly certain it was an illegal operation.

The other MC eventually tries to follow in order to save them, and after making it into the regular world, meets with some hermit (?) living there who, after having the situation explained to them, tries to discourage them from going into the factory because it's too dangerous.

They go anyway, eventually succeed at retrieving their friend, but that's still pretty early on I think. I don't remember what happens next, but it might involve dragons.

I have done some prior research with little success. [This](https://reddit.com/r/Fantasy/comments/eelndt/artsbased_magic_systems) is the most relevant thread I managed to find, but none of the stories were a match, far as I could tell from the synopses.

Comment: That's a good start. Please visit [this page](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) for some prompts to help you [edit] in more detail. Also, please visit the [tour] for more on how this site works, and how to accept answers. Lastly, I removed the [tag:fantasy-genre] tag because it's meant to only refer to the genre as a whole for discussions. It's one of our more common errors to include it in [tag:story-identification] questions.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Fantasy/comments/eelndt/artsbased_magic_systems/ might be handy for reference.

Comment: And is the factory in the "regular world"? And is the "regular world" one like ours? Modern? Medieval? Futuristic?

Comment: Thank you for the link, i have added everything i noticed from the prompts there.

Comment: This reminds me of Piers Anthony 's [Apprentice Adept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apprentice_Adept) series, even if everything doesn't match exactly.

Comment: Brandon Sanderson's book [The Rithmatist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rithmatist_(series)) has a magic system based on drawing with chalk, but the plot doesn't match your description.

Comment: FWIW, the plot of children being kidnapped to have their magic stolen from them (as well as parallel worlds) matches up plotwise with *His Dark Materials*, but no drawing-based magic...

Comment: Ohh, philip pullman! i've read that triology, but yeah that's not it.